# tableau sql server database not showing in the database list

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau 10 trial, I am able to establish connection with SQL Server database. Few other database is appearing in the drop down list, but the required database is not shown in the database list in Tableau.

Please help in resolving the same.

Comment: Does the trial have limitations of how many databases you can connect to?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Do you have rights to that database? Can you see the database in other tools (eg. SSMS)?